# Чтение данных из settings.ini

Tags: python, python-3.x, ini

У меня есть скрипт , который сначала создает пустой конфигурационных файл с основными секциями. Далее в этот конф файл пользователь должен внести свои данные. Эти данные следует считать в переменные.
Пример : **[Settings.ini]**

```
Ip : 132.32.44.12
Port = 7777
```

Теперь в скрипте :

```
def Connetion ():
    try:
        settings.read('settings.ini')
        print(" OK ")
    except IOError:
        print("Файл конфинурации не найден!")
    for line in settings:
        IP = и тут нужно получить данные из файла settings.ini
```

Comment: Откуда двоеточие в `Ip : 132.32.44.12`? Там только `равно` может быть

Comment: извиняюсь , в файле settings.ini :
IP : = айпи
Port : = порт

Answer (score 4):

Создаете `ini` с секцией:

```
[DEFAULT]
Ip = 132.32.44.12
Port = 7777
```

Используйте [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#quick-start) для работы с `ini`:

```
import configparser
settings = configparser.ConfigParser()
settings.read('settings.ini')

print(settings['DEFAULT']['Ip'])
# 132.32.44.12

print(settings['DEFAULT']['Port'])
# 7777
```

---

**PS.**

А двоеточие с равно (`:=`) не используется в [.ini](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ini). Значения от ключей всегда `=` разделяются

Comment: Этот ответ стоило бы принять ;)